# How to display LinkedIn feed/company updates into WordPress site?

Tags: feed, automatic-updates

I've been using [LinkedIn Company Updates](https://wordpress.org/plugins/company-updates-for-linkedin/) plugin for over 2 years to display linkedin feeds into wordpress site. But it's not working anymore. I've been trying over a week now to find a way to solve this. I read many forum posts, many other people have the same issue but I didn't find any solution and there is no word from this plugin developer either. And apparently, as far I know this is the only wordpress plugin I've found that displays feed from linkedin.

I found a plugin/website [walls.io](https://walls.io/) but you have to create an account in their website and login with linkedin. And they generate the feeds from linkedin in their site. And after that you will have to use iframe to show it to your site. And in my case its not helpful at all.

I really need to display linkedin feed to wordpress site. So if anyone know any other plugin or any manual API configuration method by which I can manually generate the feed and display using the API that would also work.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: At first glance the plugin uses the v1 APIs, which are now [deprecated as of the 1st May](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates). It might be as simple as changing the linkedin_api_call function to use v2, although you might have to make small changes to the code that calls this in get_updates too: I don't really know the API.

Comment: Again from a quick look at the API docs only, it looks like LinkedIn don't provide company updates in the new API. If you have a working API key then I'd investigate the API to see what you can find, but you might be out of luck.

Comment: @rup I also thought at one point that Im out of luck and the new API doesn't support feed, but then I found that walls.io is getting the feed somehow. but the problem is I will have display the feed from their website through iframe. Since they are able to display the feed there must be a way to get the feed from new version of API.

Comment: If you are looking for an altanative plugin you can use some of the plugins [here](https://www.sourcewp.com/best-wordpress-plugins-for-linkedin/)

Comment: I don't think any of those show the company updates feed though do they?

Comment: None of those plugin display feed from linkedin. Please read my question again and if you find any plugin please share.

Comment: Sorry they not working I am using **LinkedIn Master** in on my cleint's website and it works wonders i will check more plugins for you.